# $resource action encodes hash in parameters in a wrong way

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have an API. It has "filters" field and takes array of different filters. I want my resource to send request like:

> http://example.com/api/v1/myres.json?filters[filter1]=value1&filters[filter2]=value2

but when I use

`MyRes.query({filters: {filter1: "value1", filter2: "value2"}})`

it sends request like

> http://example.com/api/v1/myres.json?filters={"filter1":"value1","filter2":"value2"}

which is obviously wrong. What am I missing? Is there a way to make it work properly?